# I want the result to print ac[0] but it gives me a question mark as shown in the image.What can I do to correct it?

Tags: c

[image]I want the result to be the value of ac[0],but it is showing something confusing.The second line works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main(void){
        char a='a';
        char b='b';
        
        char ac[]={-24,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,};
        char *p=ac;
        printf("*p=%c ",*p);//this is the part that produces problem
        printf("*p=%d ",*p);//this works
    
    
        //! *(p+n)<--->ac[n]
        
    
}
```

Comment: please ignore the other irrelevant outputs...I deleted some of my code

Comment: You cannot print `*p` (the type of `char*`) in `%c`. That's misleading the output.

Comment: If you want to print `ac[n]`, Then you must pass `ac[n]` to `printf`.

Comment: Also, the first 31 characters in ASCII are non-printable. What are you supposed to do here? – maybe you wanted `int ac[] = {...}`.

Comment: `%c` is defined to convert its argument to an unsigned char, and to output the result. Typically, that will mean for -24 it will output byte 232 to your console. The specific output on your console will depend on how it is configured (ie: which character encoding it's expecting your program to be using). Possibly it's expecting utf-8, and so you get "?" representing a mal-formed utf-8 sequence. Piping the output of your program into `od -c` will show you exactly the bytes you're generating.

Comment: To improve the question, please provide the actual output of your program, and what you expect (or would like) the output to be.

Answer (score 0):

`%c` prints the character encoded by integer hold by the `char` integer value.

The most popular 7 bits system system is ASCII :

[image]

(above 0x7f they are not standard).